# Does Syncfusion Document Editor support url as source of images?

Tags: javascript, java, syncfusion

I am struggling with syncfusion Document Editor. If I serialize an image and its content is in format base64 I am able to see the image in the document. However if the source of the image
is its URL the Document Editor show an image indicating that it was unable to render the image or just doesn't find it. This is the code that I am using to transform from html to sfdt:

```java
    public static String htmlToSfdt(String html) throws Exception {
        html = "<img src=\"http://localhost:8080/app/resources/rtf/1/test.001.png\"/>";
        byte[] bytes = html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);       
        String sfdt = WordProcessorHelper.load(stream, com.syncfusion.ej2.wordprocessor.FormatType.Html);
        stream.close();
        return sfdt;
    }
```

Then I pass this sfdt to the DocumentEditor and get
[image]

Comment: To solve the issue I use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue I did this

```java
public static String htmlToSfdt(String html) throws Exception {
        html = ImageUtil.convertImagesToBase64(html);
        byte[] bytes = html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);       
        String sfdt = WordProcessorHelper.load(stream, com.syncfusion.ej2.wordprocessor.FormatType.Html);
        stream.close();
        return sfdt;
    }
```

#ImageUtil.java

```java
public static String convertImagesToBase64(String html) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<img\\s+src\\s*=\\s*\"(.*?)\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String imageUrl = matcher.group(1);
            try {
                String base64Image = imageToBase64(imageUrl);
                matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + base64Image + "\"");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String imageToBase64(String imageUrl) throws IOException {
          URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
          InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
          ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
          int bytesRead;

          while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) 
              outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

          byte[] imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
          String base64Image = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);

          inputStream.close();
          outputStream.close();

          return base64Image;
    }
```

however, I would expect that Syncfusion's Document Editor do this backstage. If somebody knows a better way it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After examining your use case, we suggest that if you want to add an image from a web or file URL, you can use the insertImage API directly on the client side. For further information on this, you can refer to the UG documentation below.

If your use case is different than that of the above one, please share with us more details about it.

[UG Link](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/api/document-editor/editor/#insertimage)

Comment: The problem is that I receive the html to render in syncfusion's Document Editor and not just the image.

Comment: You can use the insertImage API (client-side) to insert image from the web URL. Refer to the below code.

this.container.documentEditor.editor.insertImage(

     'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1337232523/photo/high-angle-view-of-a-lake-and-forest.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=EPh5_6vL4mywUc3AfLRKJCChgAs41oI9nMveOInep_0='

   );

 

UG Link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/api/document-editor/editor/#insertimage

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very helpful; however, I need to process images at backend.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the query, "however, I need to process images at backend." Please refer to the below code snippet.

Process flow:

1. Using the `DocIO` component, we are creating a Word document and inserting the image tag.
2. The created document is sent to `DocumentEditor` for opening.

```cs
public string OpenImage()
{
    //Loads the template document
    WDocument document = new WDocument();
    document.EnsureMinimal();
    document.HTMLImportSettings.ImageNodeVisited += OpenImage;
    //Html string to be inserted
    string html = "<img src=\"https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg\"/>";
    //Validates the Html string
    bool isValidHtml = document.LastSection.Body.IsValidXHTML(html, Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS.XHTMLValidationType.None);
    //When the Html string passes validation, it is inserted to the document
    if (isValidHtml)
    {

        //Appends the Html string to first paragraph in the document
        document.Sections[0].Body.Paragraphs[0].AppendHTML(html);
    }
    document.HTMLImportSettings.ImageNodeVisited -= OpenImage;
    //Hooks MetafileImageParsed event.
    WordDocument.MetafileImageParsed += OnMetafileImageParsed;
    WordDocument document1 = WordDocument.Load(document);
    document1.OptimizeSfdt = false;
    //Unhooks MetafileImageParsed event.
    WordDocument.MetafileImageParsed -= OnMetafileImageParsed;
    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document1);
    document.Dispose();
    return json;
}

/// <summary>
/// Event handler to download the image from website.
/// </summary>
private static void OpenImage(object sender, Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS.ImageNodeVisitedEventArgs args)
{
    //Check whether image src is mentioned as website URL.
    if (args.Uri.StartsWith("https://"))
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        //Download the image as stream.
        byte[] image = client.DownloadData(args.Uri);
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(image);
        //Set the retrieved image from the input HTML.
        args.ImageStream = stream;
    }
}

//Converts Metafile to raster image.
private static void OnMetafileImageParsed(object sender, MetafileImageParsedEventArgs args)
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(args.MetafileStream);
    //You can write your own method definition for converting metafile to raster image using any third-party image converter.
    args.ImageStream = ConvertMetafileToRasterImage(args.MetafileStream);
}

private static Stream ConvertMetafileToRasterImage(Stream ImageStream)
{
    //Here we are loading a default raster image as fallback.
    Stream imgStream = GetManifestResourceStream("ImageNotFound.jpg");
    return imgStream;

    //To do : Write your own logic for converting metafile to raster image using any third-party image converter(Syncfusion doesn't provide any image converter).
}
```

On the client side, you can call the above mentioned web action `OpenImage` and use the Open API.

```js
//Initialize Document Editor Container component.
let container: DocumentEditorContainer = new DocumentEditorContainer();

container.appendTo('#DocumentEditorContainer');

document.getElementById('import').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let http: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //add your url in which you want to open document inside the ""
    let content = { fileUrl: "" };
    let baseurl: string = "/api/documenteditor/OpenImage";
    http.open("POST", baseurl, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    http.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (http.readyState === 4) {
            if (http.status === 200 || http.status === 304) {
                //open the SFDT text in Document Editor
                container.documentEditor.open(http.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    http.send(JSON.stringify(content));
});
```